# How to wordcount using hadoop not using jar file

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Many hadoop wordcount code uses jar file and need command `hdfs dfs -put inputfile` and `hadoop jar jarfile wordcount input output`

But I want to receive directly the file in eclipse and directly do wordcount if I run the eclipse code and make txt file having result. How can I write the code

This is my wordcount code

WordCount.java

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
 
public class WordCount {
 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        if(args.length !=2)
        {
            System.err.println("WordCount : 2개의 인수가 필요합니다.");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        
        Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
        
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        
        Path path = new Path(args[1]);
        
        if(hdfs.exists(path)){
            hdfs.delete(path);
        }
        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
 
}
```

WordCountMapper.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 
public class WordCountMapper extends
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString()," \t\n\r!?.,#$%^&*()-=_+/'");
            
            while(itr.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
                
            }
        }
}
```

WordcountReducer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
 
public class WordCountReducer extends 
Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
 
    

    private IntWritable res = new IntWritable();
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;
        for(IntWritable val : values)
        {
            sum += val.get();
            //sum++;
        }
        res.set(sum);
        context.write(key, res);
    }
}
```

I'm not good at English. and I have little hadoop code skill. Please understand.

Comment: You can run the main function directly. You don't need any JAR file, however, MapReduce isn't really used by many Hadoop developers, and better tools like Spark exist

Comment: I know it has many other useful tools but I have no time to change other tools ㅠㅠ If I change to use Spark, Is it more fast to make wordcount?

Comment: Yes. Word count can be written in 3 lines https://spark.apache.org/examples.html Besides, _most_ Hadoop clusters that exist in companies nowadays _already have Spark_ installed